# Tagging Multiple users in a Status in Titanium Mobile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, titanium-mobile, tagging

Help me with tagging multiple Friend's with a status which I'm updating via my device from my app. Here's what I'm doing

```js
var data = {
    link : "http://www.appcelerator.com",
    name : "Appcelerator Titanium (iteration " + iter + ")",
    tags : ("1234","5678"),



    accesstoken : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",

    message : "Awesome SDKs for building desktop and mobile apps  ",
    place : "XXXXXXXX",

    caption : "Appcelerator Titanium (iteration " + iter + ")",
    picture : "http://developer.appcelerator.com/assets/img/DEV_titmobile_image.png",

    description : "You've got the ideas, now you've got the power. Titanium translates your hard won web skills..."
};
fb.requestWithGraphPath('me/feed', data, 'POST', showRequestResult);
```

When i run this only the 2nd user with the id above mentioned "5678",gets tagged and not the 1st user.
I also tried other methods like,

```js
tags1 : {
        'tags' : [{
            "id" : "12345"

        }, {
            "id" : "12345"

        }, {
            "id" : "56789"

        }, {
            "id" : "457889"

        }, {
            "id" : "567890"

        }, {
            "id" : "987654"

        }, {
            "id" : "98765"

        }]
    },
```

I get an error in as (#100) param tags must be an array

I also tried this  METHOD

```js
var idnos = [];
idNos[0] = "123456";
idNos[1] = "4567";
idNos[2] = "456788";
idNos[3] = "45678989";
idNos[4] = "987654";
idNos[5] = "4567889";

tags = idnos
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter for the tag field should be an array. So instead of this:

```
var data = {
    link : "http://www.appcelerator.com",
    name : "Appcelerator Titanium (iteration " + iter + ")",
    tags : ("1234","5678"),



    accesstoken : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",

    message : "Awesome SDKs for building desktop and mobile apps  ",
    place : "XXXXXXXX",

    caption : "Appcelerator Titanium (iteration " + iter + ")",
    picture : "http://developer.appcelerator.com/assets/img/DEV_titmobile_image.png",

    description : "You've got the ideas, now you've got the power. Titanium translates your hard won web skills..."
};
```

Use:

```
var data = {
    link : "http://www.appcelerator.com",
    name : "Appcelerator Titanium (iteration " + iter + ")",
    tags : [{ "tag_uid":"1234" },{ "tag_uid":"5678" }],



    accesstoken : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",

    message : "Awesome SDKs for building desktop and mobile apps  ",
    place : "XXXXXXXX",

    caption : "Appcelerator Titanium (iteration " + iter + ")",
    picture : "http://developer.appcelerator.com/assets/img/DEV_titmobile_image.png",

    description : "You've got the ideas, now you've got the power. Titanium translates your hard won web skills..."
};
```